# Let $M$ be a non-zero $3\times 3$ matrix satisfying $M^3=O$

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be a non-zero $3\times 3$ matrix satisfying $M^3=0$, where $0$ is the $3\times 3$ zero matrix. Then
$(A)\det(\frac{1}{2}M^2+M+I)\neq0$
$(B)\det(\frac{1}{2}M^2-M+I)=0$
$(C)\det(\frac{1}{2}M^2+M+I)=0$
$(D)\det(\frac{1}{2}M^2-M+I)\neq0$
This is a multiple correct choice type question.More than one may be correct answers.

---

My attempt:
Let $M$ be a non-singular matrix,therefore its inverse exists.
$M^3=0$
Multiply both sides by $M^{-1}$ to get,$M^2=0$.
Again multiply both sides by $M^{-1}$ to get,$M=0$
But this is a contradiction.So $M$ is a singular matrix.Its inverse does not exist.
But i dont know how to solve further.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is O? Also, in your attempt, why are you assuming your matrix is non-singular? Is that part of the statement?

Comment: Note: it is not possible for $M$ to be non-singular, because then $det(M)\neq 0$, but also $0=det(0)=det(M^3)=det(M)^3$.

Comment: Do you know about the Jordan normal form?

Comment: BY $O$ do you mean $0$?

Comment: By $O$,question means null matrix.

Comment: If the matrix was invertible its third power can’t be zero.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of above is really not necessary
 $$\left(\frac{M^2}{2}+M+I\right)\left(\frac{M^2}{2}-M+I\right)=I$$

It is easy from here onwards

Answer (score 7):

$M^3=0$ implies $\det(M-xI)=-x^3$ (since $M$ satisfies its own characteristic equation). Decompose expression in question into linear factors:
$$\det(\frac 1 2M^2\pm M+I)=\frac 1 8\det(M-x_{\pm1}I)\det(M-x_{\pm2}I)=\frac 1 8x_{\pm1}^3x_{\pm2}^3=\frac 1 82^3=1$$ where $x_{\pm}1,x_{\pm2}$ are roots of $x^2\pm2x+2=0$ and hence $x_{\pm1}x_{\pm2}=2$.

Answer (score 6):

If we put $M$ in [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), for some invertible matrix $Q$ we will have $$M=QAQ^{-1}$$
where $$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&a&0\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$
where $a,b$ are each $0$ or $1$ (not both $0$ since $M\neq 0$).
Hence, we write $$0.5M^2+M+I=0.5QAQ^{-1}QAQ^{-1}+QAQ^{-1}+QIQ^{-1}=$$
$$=Q(0.5A^2+A+I)Q^{-1}$$
Taking determinants, we get $$det(Q)det(0.5A^2+A+I)det(Q)^{-1}=det(0.5A^2+A+I)=1$$ since $$0.5A^2+A+I=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&a&\frac{ab}{2}\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

The other three questions are similar.

Comment: Sir,cant this question be solved without Jordan normal form?Jordan form is not in our syllabus.@vadim123

Comment: It's difficult to know what is and is not on your syllabus when your question does not give context for the question.  I gave one of several standard ways to solve this problem.